# Can't figure out how to index a Dict with a Symbol

Tags: julia

I'm reading "Getting Started with Julia" book and it has the following example:

```
d3 = [:A => 100, :B => 200]
d3[:C] = 300
```

When I run it, I get an error

```
ERROR: ArgumentError: invalid index: C
Stacktrace:
 [1] setindex!(::Array{Pair{Symbol,Int64},1}, ::Int64, ::Symbol) at .\abstractarray.jl:967
```

The book is for an earlier version of Julia, but I can't find anywhere in the manuals how to address `Dict` items by `Symbol` correctly in the current version.

Comment: Have you tried d3 = Dict(:A => 100, :B => 200)? That works for me in version 0.5.2 and 0.6.0 - just newer syntax. I'm not sure it has anything to do with using a symbol as a key.

Comment: Yeah, that worked. My example created an array of `Pairs` not a dict thus not working as inteded. That book is really deprecated by now...

Comment: @ephemeris it's a good book, but yes, that version of julia is pretty old by now, not least because of julia's phenomenal rate of deprecation from one version to the next! (which, fair enough, it _is_ still technically in version 0!). Having said that, in terms of that textbook, it can work to your benefit, since you can see how the language evolved (and why). So, for every section your read in the book, check the current documentation in the REPL to see what and how it's changed; that should get you to grips with the language a lot more than if you were just passively reading the book anyway!